# Can I dynamically call imported file names?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a seven day forecast react app. I have an images folder that has 28 icons for weather types split between day and night versions. Those images are imported like so into a component (for brevity I will only show 4 options):

```
import {
    dayclear, daycloudy,

    nightclear, nightcloudy
} from '../images'
```

Depending on the type of weather when this component is called, I'm trying to dynamically name an image source. Is there a way to concatenate a object name dynamically? Ex:

```
<img src={this.props.timeOfDay + this.props.weather} alt="Weather Image" />
```

I'm looking for that source to end up being the object name of the imported image.

Answer (score 3):

try to store your images in a object like this:

```
const IMAGES = {
  dayclear,
  nightclear,
  ...
}
```

then create a weather name with

```
const { timeOfDay, weather } = this.props
const weatherName = `${timeOfDay > condition ? 'day' : 'night'}${weather}`
```

finally add it to src of image:

```
<img src={IMAGES[weatherName]} alt="Weather Image" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, there is a way.

First, write the import statement like this.

```js
import * as WeatherIcons from '../images'
```

Then add the image to the `src` attribute as mentioned below.

```js
<img src={WeatherIcons[this.props.timeOfDay + this.props.weather]} alt="Weather Image" />
```

Here I consider that,

- Values for `timeOfDay` prop can be *day* or *night*
- Values for `weather` prop can be *clear* or *cloudy*